# how to select multi select option in drop down using jquery

Tags: javascript

```
 <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes('dLang')">
            <select>
                <option>Select an option</option>
            </select>
            <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxes" id="dLang" style="overflow-x: hidden;">

            <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three"/>Czech</label>
            <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three"/>Danish</label>
            <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three"/>Dutch</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#This code working fine but i want to add scrollbar here.Can any one help?#

Comment: Which question would you like us to answer? Also you don't seem to be using JQuery in the given code (despite the tag). Would you like our answer to use JQuery?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: check this link http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this snippet. Is this what you need?

```css
.multiSelect {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<select class="multiSelect" multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

(Hold down CTRL to select multiple elements)

Answer (score 0):

```
This is you should need to check : http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-using-jQuery.aspx     

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=your id name ]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```